# warning use of undefined constant.. this will throw an error in future version of php

Tags: php, deprecation-warning

This should be enough for someone to correct my issue - I'm very much a newbie at this.

It's a short bit of code to strip spaces from the ends of strings submitted in forms.

The warning message is saying "Use of undefined constant mystriptag - assumed 'mystriptag' (this will throw an error..."

How should I change this?

```
function mystriptag($item)
{
    $item = strip_tags($item);
}

array_walk($_POST, mystriptag);
function t_area($str){
    $order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
    $replace = ', ';
    $newstr = str_replace($order, $replace, $str);
    return $newstr;
}
```

Comment: Failure to quote the string makes this an Off-topic Typo question.

Answer (score 1):

You must use single quote in order for PHP to understand your parameter `mystriptag`.
So the correct line would be :
`array_walk($_POST, 'mystriptag');`